# How should I extract and combine parts of files based on a common text string effectively in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, text

Suppose I have two similar files:

**a.yaml**

```
data:
- name: a1
  args: ["cmd", "something"]
  config:
  - name: some
    val: thing

- name: a2
  args: ["cmd2", "else"]

[...other array values...]

tags: ["something-in-a"]
values: ["else-in-a"]

substitutions:
  key1: a-value
  key2: a-value
  key3: a-value
```

**b.yaml**

```
data:
- name: b1
  args: ["cmd", "something"]
  config:
  - name: some
    val: thing

- name: b2
  args: ["cmd2", "else"]

[...other array values...]

tags: ["something-in-b"]
values: ["else-in-b"]

substitutions:
  key1: b-value
  key2: b-value
  key3: b-value
```

My goal is to combine parts of a and b file such that I have a new file which consists of file content before `substitutions:` from `b.yaml` and content including and after `substitutions:` from `a.yaml`

So in this case, my desired output would be like this:

**c.yaml**

```
data:
- name: b1
  args: ["cmd", "something"]
  config:
  - name: some
    val: thing

- name: b2
  args: ["cmd2", "else"]

[...other array values...]

tags: ["something-in-b"]
values: ["else-in-b"]

substitutions:
  key1: a-value
  key2: a-value
  key3: a-value
```

The parts before and after `substitutions:` in both file contents might have different lengths.

Currently, my method is like this:

```
head -q -n `awk '/substitution/ {print FNR-1}' b.yaml` b.yaml >! c.yaml ; \
tail -q -n `awk '/substitution/ {ROWNUM=FNR} END {print NR-ROWNUM+1}' a.yaml` a.yaml >> c.yaml; \
rm a.yaml b.yaml; mv c.yaml a.yaml; # optional newfile renaming to original
```

But I wonder if there's an alternative or better method for combining parts of different files based on a common text string in bash?

Comment: If some program loads and dumps the YAML you can easily end up with `substitutions: {key1: a-value, key2: a-value, key3: a-value}`, on one line which is semantically equivalent to your block-style. As you accept an answer not using bash, but a program called from bash, you should consider using a programa that contains a YAML parser, and that can deal with those nuances, instead of dumb line oriented processing.

Comment: @Anthon I might I phrase and tag the question a bit wrong. Yes, I definitely agree with using parser when using yaml / json especially if we're developing a program that need to read/write with them. But my question isn't about yaml, it's about combining any text files which has a common string, and I used my yaml files as an example.

Comment: Also, although I'm using yaml, I'm not the one who consumes the yaml files, it's an external program. The yaml files only serve as regular text files which are all written by me. So, I know and can enforce the exact structure of how these files should be. Hence, using parsers aren't necessary in this case (they also added overheads for installing and writing a program to process them instead of bash scripts which are readily available in most unix systems by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`, you  just need to flag the flow based on the string:

```
awk '$1 == "substitutions:"{skip = FNR==NR ? 1:0}!skip' b.yaml a.yaml
```

**Explaination:**

- `FNR==NR`: if true, process lines in the first file `b.yaml`, otherwise the 2nd file `a.yaml`
- `!skip`: if TRUE, print the line, otherwise skip the line.

Comment: That is a very clever was to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    head -B9999 'substitutions:' a.yaml |  head -n -1
    head -A9999 'substitutions:' b.yaml
} > c.yaml
```

A oneliner:

```
{ head -B9999 'substitutions:' a.yaml |  head -n -1; head -A9999 'substitutions:' b.yaml; } > c.yaml
```

The `-A9999` and `-B9999` are a bit dirty, here's a solution with sed's:

```
{
      sed '/substitutions:/,$d' a.yaml
      echo substitutions:
      sed '1,/substitutions:/d' b.yaml
} > c.yaml
```